# typeorm can I force it to update an entity (with hooks) even no changes in the entity?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I am going to implement multi-language on a model, the structure is

```
const post = {
  id: "123",
  publishAt: "2020-09-04T00:00:00",
  version: 1,
  translations: [
    {
      locale: "en-US",
      title: "hello world"
    }
  ]
}
```

To store inside a relation database such as `mysql`, I need 2 table `posts` and `post_translations`

and thus 2 entities for typeorm

```
@Entity()
class Post {
  @VersionColumn()
  version: number;

  @Column()
  publishAt: Date;

  @OneToMany(
    (type) => PostTranslation,
    (translation) => translation.post,
    { cascade: true }
  )
  translations: PostTranslation[];

  @BeforeUpdate()
  beforeUpdate() {
    // do something
  }
}

@Entity()
class PostTranslation {
  @Column()
  postId: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @ManyToOne((type) => Post, (post) => post.translations)
  post: Post;
}
```

I am using `repository.save(post)` for creating/ updating records. If there are some changes inside `post` entity, such as `publishAt`, `@BeforeUpdate()` and `@VersionColumn()` will be triggered. But if there are no changes, they will not be trigger ([reference](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/listeners-and-subscribers#beforeupdate)).

It means that if I only modify the title from `PostTranslations`, and persist the changes via `repository.save(post)`, it does not see changes and not going to trigger `@BeforeUpdate()` and `@VersionColumn()`. But the `title` (which lives in `PostTranslations`) is actually part of `Post` to me.

Is there any ways to ask typeorm to update the entity if some related entities changed during cascade persist?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, if there's no change in data being passed, the update method won't commit any change. The workaround I've found for this one is to update another field like a updated_at i.e from your code above:

```
@Entity()
class Post {
  @VersionColumn()
  version: number;

  @Column()
  publishAt: Date;

  @Column() // new column/field
  updatedAt: Date;
// the rest of your post entity
...
```

Then, whenever you pass the object to be updated, you update this date manually. It could be with a repository or something, such as:

```
... 
post.updatedAt = new Date()
postRepository.save(post)
```

This will see some difference in old data, and then it would "force" the save. Hope it helps